# Regarding SQL changing the table space

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

```
CREATE   TABLE "ONESPEKSDEV"."ABC_AGIHAN_AKTIVITI_OUTPUT"   (
 "ID_TRANSAKSI" NUMBER(11,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1     MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1     START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOT NULL ENABLE,
 "TAHUN_KEWANGAN" NUMBER(4,0),
 "TARIKH_KEWANGAN" DATE,
 "JABATAN"      VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
 "KODPTJ"       VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
 "JUM_BANDING"  NUMBER(14,2),
 "KODAKTIVITI"  VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
 "KOD_PROG_AKT" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
 "VOT_DANA"     VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
 "AKAUN"        VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
 "AGIHAN_NILAI" NUMBER(14,2),
 "AGIHAN_ADHOC" NUMBER(14,2),
 "AMAUN_2"      NUMBER(14,2),
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID_TRANSAKSI") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255
 COMPUTE STATISTICS STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 TABLESPACE "ONESPEKSDEVTS" ENABLE   )
 SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255   NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE   (
 INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0
 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
 CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT   )
TABLESPACE "ONESPEKSDEVTS" ;
```

this is in ONESPEKSDEV connection how to change another ONESPEKS connection

Answer (score 0):

You can simply alter the table and index:

```
ALTER TABLE ONESPEKSDEV.ABC_AGIHAN_AKTIVITI_OUTPUT MOVE TABLESPACE ONESPEKS;
ALTER INDEX ONESPEKSDEV.ID_TRANSAKSI REBUILD TABLESPACE ONESPEKS;
```